# Warning- "SAPEdit" description mismatch, " The object was not found using the test object description.Check the object properties

Tags: hp-uft

I'm a new entrant to UFT and while i'm trying to access the columns of a webtable, to identify the test object "SAPEdit", UFT takes a longer time  and throws a warning "SAPEdit" -description mismatch. The object was not found using the test object description.Check the object's properties. Kindly suggest me a workaround to clear this warning and speed up the test object identification. BTW, i'm not using descriptive programming.

Code follows:

```
strPENXPath = strTblXPath & "/TBODY[1]/TR[" & iRow & "]/TD[1]/SPAN[1]/INPUT[1]"
Browser("SAP Transaction iView").Page("SAP Transaction iView").SAPFrame("Child Care Quota Program_2").SAPEdit("SAPEdit").SetTOProperty "xpath", strPENXPath
oPersonnelNo = Browser("SAP Transaction iView").Page("SAP Transaction iView").SAPFrame("Child Care Quota Program_2").SAPEdit("SAPEdit").GetROProperty("value")
If iPersonnelNo <> oPersonnelNo Then 
   strMessage=strMessage & "Failed -Personnelno Type "  
End If
```

Answer (score 1):

This means that the object's description doesn't match an object in your application.

There are several ways to fix this problem.

Probably the simplest one is to [Maintenance Run Mode](https://uft-help.saas.hpe.com/en/14.00/UFT_Help/Content/User_Guide/Running_Tests_with_Maintenance_Mode.htm).

From the `Run` menu select **Maintenance Run Mode...** then when UFT will see an object it can't find it will ask you to [point at the object](https://uft-help.saas.hpe.com/en/14.00/UFT_Help/Content/User_Guide/CS_Object_Not_Found_Screen.htm) and then it will suggest a solution.

Comment: Hi Motti, i tried running in maintenance mode. its still the same...following is the code im using.

Comment: strPENXPath = strTblXPath & "/TBODY[1]/TR[" & iRow & "]/TD[1]/SPAN[1]/INPUT[1]"
  Browser("SAP Transaction iView").Page("SAP Transaction iView").SAPFrame("Child Care Quota Program_2").SAPEdit("SAPEdit").SetTOProperty "xpath",strPENXPath
  oPersonnelNo = Browser("SAP Transaction iView").Page("SAP Transaction iView").SAPFrame("Child Care Quota Program_2").SAPEdit("SAPEdit").GetROProperty("value")
 
  If iPersonnelNo <> oPersonnelNo Then
   strMessage=strMessage & "Failed -Personnelno Type "
  End If

Comment: I see you are using an XPath, check if the XPath is correct by using it in the browser's dev tools with [document.evaluate](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document/evaluate)

Comment: how do i check that? sorry Motti... i dont know what do you mean by Browser's dev tools?

Comment: Open your browser and press `F12` this will open your developer tools. You can run JavaScript from that window including `document.evaluate` (which  I linked before)

Comment: Hi Motti!! I checked the Xpath...its correct.is there anything else i need to check?

Comment: Sorry @shilparamanjeneya, I don't know what else could be the problem. I've added the code from your comment into the question so other people will have an easier time answering it.

Comment: appreciate your initiative to help me....hopefully will find an alternative. thanks a lot